# Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>] error

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, django-1.9, ubuntu-16.04

I am constantly getting same error when i do python manage.py runserver. There was no such error when i have ubuntu 15.10. This got started when i upgraded my ubuntu to 16.04. This question might look duplicate but i have tried solution provided to this question like i have applied the command dpkg --configure -a, i have done apt-get update,upgrade,dist-upgrade, clean, -f install. I have reinstalled python2.7 and python3 too but no success though. Here is my screenshot while trying to run my django application [image]

i got this after re-installing python

[image]
Could anyone please help me?

**bashrc file**

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
export PYTHONHOME="/usr/bin/python"
echo $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON
echo 'tushant'
# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"


export VIRTUALENV_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python3"
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh


export NVM_DIR="/home/tushant/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm \n. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

### AndroidDev PATH
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/tushant/Android/Sdk

export PATH=${PATH}:/home/tushant/Android/Sdk/tools

export PATH=${PATH}:/home/tushant/Android/Sdk/platform-tools


export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Try to reinstall apt-get install --reinstall python -y; Also after that relogin (to reread PYTHON_* env).

Comment: I reinstalled it again like you said but still not working. I have attached an image of reinstalling python like you said.

Comment: dpkg -l|grep python |grep ii| awk '{print $2}'|grep -E "^python"| xargs apt-get --reinstall install

Comment: But it can break your system because of reinstallation of all packages with name start python

Comment: Could you please provide me the safe method? I dont want to break my system. :)

Comment: You should check which py-packages are installed with `dpkg -l|grep python |grep ii| awk '{print $2}'|grep -E "^python"` and reinstall the "buggy"

Comment: Also check that there is PYTHONPATH `echo $PYTHONPATH`. PS: Any chance that you are redefined it in `.bashrc`?

Comment: I have updated with .bashrc file.

Comment: This post may help : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184504/linux-mint-13-problem-no-module-named-site

Comment: Did that too but still not working

Comment: What do you get if you type `echo $PYTHONHOME` ?

Comment: tried both echo $PYTHONPATH and echo $PYTHONHOME. They both show no result. @ empty line is shown on terminal.

Comment: If you type `which python` you should get the directory where python is installed, probably `/usr/bin`. Try to set manually PYTHONHOME to `/usr` if it is the case by `export PYTHONHOME = /usr`

Comment: I meant `export PYTHONHOME =/usr` without the space in the above comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110139/discussion-between-tushant-and-jacques-gaudin).

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar. Turns out uninstalling base python removes symlink and for reason, when reinstalling, it doesn't symlink automatically.

Running this helps to link python to path

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```